# How to Sort in Alphabetical order the Options in Select Element in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

newbie here I have this PHP code and I'm trying to sort in alphabetical order the 2nd option data in a select element. What block of code should I add in the existing code below to achieve this?

```
 <?php if ( $enmse_de == 1 ) { // SHOW EXPLORER? ?>
    <div class="enmse-selector <?php echo $enmse_ddval ?>">
    <?php if ( $enmse_hsd == 0 ) {  ?>
      <select name="enmse_series" class="enmse_series">
        <option value="0">- <?php echo $enmse_explorerbrowseseries; ?> -</option>
        <?php foreach ($enmse_series as $enmse_s) {  ?>
          <option value="<?php echo '&amp;enmse_sid=' .  $enmse_s->series_id; ?>">
          <?php echo stripslashes($enmse_s->s_title); ?></option>       
        <?php }; ?>    
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sort the `$enmse_series` array wtih `s_title` alphabetically.
You can simply achieve this by usning php build-in functins.
First you hvae to change the database return array of object to array of array. After that,
add this block of code before `foreach` loop.

```
// as of PHP 5.5.0 you can use array_column()
$s_title  = array_column($enmse_series, 's_title');

// Sort the data with s_title ascending
// Add $enmse_series as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($s_title, SORT_ASC, $enmse_series);
```

For more details, referrence php [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Big thanks for this, I will give it a try, I'm not clear though on how to implement this!